# how to tell big.matrix to treat certain columns as vectors

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a big data set that includes character variables of many different values.  I'm trying to read the data as `big.matrix` and then use `biglm.big.matrix` to build linear models.  However, since `big.matrix` will convert all character vectors to factors and the character labels will be lost.  I decided to create a lookup table outside of R for my character columns and use numbers to represent different levels for R.  However, I do not know how to tell `big.matrix` these columns should be considered factors instead of numerics.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `read.table.ffdf` but can you just use it's `x` argument? From `?read.table.ffdf`:

```
x
   NULL or an optional ffdf object to which the read records are appended. If this is provided,
   it defines crucial features that are otherwise determnined during the 'first' chunk of
   reading: vmodes, colnames, colClasses, sequence of predefined levels. In order to also read
   the first chunk into such predefined ffdf, an x with 1 row is treated special: instead of
   appending the first row will be overwritten. This is necessary because we cannot provide x 
   with zero rows (we cannot create ff vectors with zero elements).
```

You can define corresponding columns in `x` as factors with given levels and then use it as a template.

Comment: Thanks @mdsummer. When I was answering this question, the title was "how to read numeric vector as factors using read.table.ffdf"

Comment: oh, whoops - OP is now also asking on r-help